# How can I use a demultiplexer to transfer an analogue signal from a neurostimulator and transfer it over to the 8 different channels of the demux?

Tags: microcontroller

**Device providing the signal: ISIS
Neurostimulator (INOMED)

Signal current: 0.6 mA - 3 mA**

I want to transfer this signal and generate it across the different channels of the demultiplexer. I am using a 1:8 demux 74HC4051. I just want the pure signal to be transferred over the different channels of the demux. How do I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by pure signal?

Comment: Why don't you use 8 buffer amplifiers?

Comment: @VoltageSpike by pure signal I meant to transfer the signal from the neurostimulator without turning it into a digital signal